# WPF MVVM: Filter by member displayed in the listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, collectionview

I have gridview within a listview. There is a column, "Department" that is bound to a property "Department" in the model and also it has associated a conveter.

Converter takes the value that comes from the property and displays it in another form (with another string).

For example, if this property "Department" has a value of "100AB" in the column is displayed as "Financial", if value comes to "200CB" in the column is displayed "Administration" and so on...

My problem is when filtering listview using a filter. Internally it filter by "100AB", "200CB" instead of the value displayed "Financial" and "Administration", so how to solve this?

**View (xaml)**:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
          Name="MyListView" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=View}" 

<GridViewColumn Header="Department" Width="190"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Department, Converter={StaticResource DeptTypeConverter}}">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

**Converter**:

```
public class DeptTypeConverter: IValueConverter
{
    #region Constants

    private const string DeptFinancialType = "100AB";
    private const string DeptAdminType = "200CB";

    private const string DeptFinancialView = "Finanacial";
    private const string DeptAdminView = "Administration";

    #endregion

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Do the conversion from drink type to present it in the view
        string s = (string)value;
        if (s == DeptFinancialType )
            return DeptFinancialView;
        else if (s == DeptAdminType)
            return DeptAdminView;
        else
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Cannot convert, unknown value {0}", value));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Do the conversion from presentation to data type
        string s = (string)value;
        if (s.Equals(DeptFinancialView, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return DeptFinancialType;
        else if (s.Equals(DeptAdminView, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return DeptAdminType;
        else
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Cannot convert, unknown value {0}", value));
    }
}
```

**Filter in view model**:

```
private CollectionView view;

public CollectionView View
{
    get
    {
        return this.view;
    }

    private set
    {
        if (this.view == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.view = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("View");
    }
}

// This code in constructor
this.View = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.MyListView);
this.View.Filter = UserFilter;
//

private bool MyFilter(object item)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TextToFilter))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        DataModel m = (item as DataModel);
        bool result = (m.Department.IndexOf(this.TextToFilter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);

        return result;
    }
}
```

I have other fields in the filter which I filter by but for simplicity I have not specified within MyFilter method. This fields are not using a converter, it is not necessary in this case, only is necessary in the case I have provided.

DataModel is the data model and contains "Department" property which view is bound to.

this.TextToFilter is a textbox in the view to filter by.

**ATTEMPT #1**:

Instead of using ConvertBack in DeptTypeConverter I have used Convert (no need to modify anything within Convert method). Below is working correctly.

```
private bool MyFilter(object item)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TextToFilter))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        DataModel m = (item as DataModel);

        bool result = (new Converters.DeptTypeConverter().Convert(m.Department, null, null, null).ToString().IndexOf(this.TextToFilter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);

        return result;
    }
}
```

m.Department contains the internal stored value (not the displayed one).

I think its better to use Convert rather than ConvertBack as user types the displayed text (no the value stored internally) when searching. Using ConvertBack requires more logic to implement and it is not as easy as using simply Convert.

If someone has any other better idea, please share. Any idea or improvements are always welcome. As far as possible I would like to not break the MVVM pattern architecture.

Comment: Use a CollectionViewSource - http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html

Comment: @ajg Yes I am using it, see my update post, I have posted more code.

Comment: OK. Not sure then as don't think you can bind the display member back easily. You could change your ConvertBack method to not throw an exception if no match, just return string.Empty. Then call ConvertBack in the filter method and use the value for filtering instead of the TextToFilter if its not empty? Not sure i like this in MVVM though.

Comment: You are probably best getting rid of the IValueConverter entirely and doing the conversion in the ViewModel - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769511/getting-a-reference-to-the-viewmodel-from-an-ivalueconverter

Comment: @ajg Yes, I think is the best option to take advantage of the converter. But, if I call convertBack from my filter, which parameters I have to pass to the method? value is the value I want to convert, but what about others, I mean, targettype, parameter and culture?

Comment: you aren't using the other parameters so it doesn't matter. Pass nulls.

Comment: @ajg Finally I have used Convert method instead of ConvertBack, see my updated post Attempt #1

Answer (score 0):

I do feel the best way to do this would be to not use an IValueConverter at all. I would change your DataModel class to add a new DepartmentDisplay property. Use the DepartmentDisplay property for the GridViewColumn binding and for filtering, and Department for whatever you do with the data after the grid is displayed. This would be the simplest and most MVVM solution, it removes the IValueConverter entirely.

DataModel....

```
public string Department { get; set; }

public string DepartmentDisplay
{
    get
    {
        if (Department == "100AB")
            return "Financial";
        if (Department == "200CB")
            return "Administration";

        return "";
    }
}
```

View...

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Department" Width="190"
            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DepartmentDisplay}">
```

ViewModel...

```
private bool MyFilter(object item)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TextToFilter))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        DataModel m = (item as DataModel);
        bool result = (m.DepartmentDisplay.IndexOf(this.TextToFilter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);

        return result;
    }
}
```